# $C(A)$ is $\|\cdot\|_2$-dense in $\ell_2(A)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, lp-spaces

Let $A \neq \varnothing$ and $\cal {F}$$(A) = \{F \subset A \mid F$ is finite$\}$.

Define $\ell_2 (A) =L^2(A, 2^A, \mu_C)$, with $\mu_C$ the counting measure.

Let $C(A) = \{f: A \to \Bbb C, \exists \ F \in \cal F$$(A) \mid f = 0$ on $A \setminus F \}$.

The following holds:

> $C(A)$ is $\|\cdot\|_2$-dense in $\ell_2(A)$.

Where can I find a proof of this claim?

Background: it was given to us in class as an admitted theorem. I do not think that the proof is very advanced, so I would like to see one.

Comment: Can you prove this in the case that $A$ is countable (or in particular, $A$ is $\Bbb N$)?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes: if $(x_n) \in \ell_2$, then $\sum |x_n|^2 < \infty$, so $\lim_n \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} |x_n|^2 = 0$. Then we put $y_n = (x_1,...,x_n,0,...,0,...)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $f:A \to \Bbb C$ is in $\ell_2(A)$ (that is, if $|f|^2$ has a convergent integral with respect to counting measure), then it is zero on all but countably many points.

Hence, we can apply the proof from the case of $A=\Bbb N$.